# How to properly generate HTML in a JavaScript widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been following this [tutorial](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/) on how to make JS widget. However I noticed that manually building html with plain JavaScript is not DRY. I am planning to build a form, tables etc. in a JS widget. Whats the best way to do this?

```
 $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
   var fruits = ["Apples", "Mangoes", "Banana"];
   var myHtml = "<ul>";
   $(fruits).each(function(i){
      myHtml += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
   });
   myHtml += "</ul>";
   $('#example-widget-container').html(myHtml);
 });
```

Comment: This is not plain JS. It's jQuery. If you're generating HTML in Javascript often, use some sort of templating engine.

Comment: try to use the jQuery append method (since you're using jQuery anyway), `$('#example-widget-container').append(myHtml);`

Comment: EJS, Hogan.js, Dust.js, etc.- I like Hogan.

Answer (score 1):

if you want one of your `divs or containers` to continuously grow while you build dynamic content, without losing older content, use `jQuery.append`

```
$('#example-widget-container').append(myHtml);
```

this is probably the cleanest way. Or you can do other things like

```
var html = $('#example-widget-container').html();
newHtml = yourContent;
$('#example-widget-container').html(html + newHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can generate html content in different ways :

1. Create HTML with a string directly :

   ```
   $("#sampleArea").append('<div class="' + newClass + '">' + newText + '</div>');
   ```
2. Create HTML with [jQuery Api wrapping](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) :

   ```
   $("#sampleArea").append($('<div/>',{class : newClass}).text(newText));
   ```
3. Use a template engine in Javascript (like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)) :

   ```
   <script id="exampleTpl" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
       <div class="{{class}}">{{text}}</div>
   </script>

   <script>
   var data = {
       class: newClass,
       text: newText
   }
   var template = $('#exampleTpl').html();
   var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
   $('#sampleArea').append(html);
   </script>
   ```

The best solution will depends of your use.